# copy and pasting the data values from one excel to another excel to the next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

i need to copy a set of data from one excel file to another excel file.

while pasting i also need to paste them into the next empty row in the desired column.

Is there any macro coding for this process please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly all you need to do is:

- Determine the last row used in the Copy sheet, then
- Copy from the original into that row + 1.

Something like this should suffice, though it's quick and dirty. Also I've made it more "detailed" (and therefore less efficient) than it needs to be to try to make the process clearer. (You don't really need all of the variables that I've declared but I've put them in to make the logic more transparent.)

```
Sub PasteToFollowingRow()

    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng_Source As Excel.Range
    Dim rng_NextRowDown As Excel.Range
    Dim l_LastRow As Long, l_LastColumn As Long

    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("generation_copy")

    l_LastRow = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    l_LastColumn = wks.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'Assumes that you'll never copy just one cell...
    If (l_LastRow = 1 And l_LastColumn = 1) Then
        Set rng_NextRowDown = wks.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        Set rng_NextRowDown = wks.Cells(l_LastRow + 1, 1)
    End If

    Set rng_Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("generation").UsedRange

    rng_Source.Copy rng_NextRowDown

ExitPoint:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng_NextRowDown = Nothing
    Set rng_Source = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    On Error Goto 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description

    Resume ExitPoint

End Sub
```

Comment: received an error saying ,subscript out of range !!

Comment: i dont where should i edit in your given code can you guide me

Comment: Are the worksheets actually named "generation" and "generation_copy"? If they aren't, then the code won't be able to find them in the Worksheets collection. If that's the problem either rename the sheets or change the sheet names in the code. If that doesn't work set a breakpoint at the first line of code (the Set wks... etc) one and step through the code to find out which line makes it jump to the error handler. But dollars to donuts, the subscript out of range error will relate to the sheet names as above.

Comment: Incidentally, if you aren't familiar with breakpoints: (a) Put your cursor onto the Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("generation_copy") line and press [F9] then (b) Press [F8] to step through each line of the code.